# How to add an image to an organization in Docker Hub ?

Tags: docker, github, webhooks, dockerhub

I have a personal account, on Docker Hub, linked to my GitHub account, where I can build an image of my repository normally.

Now I've created an organization on GitHub where I've forked my code. I've also created an organization on Docker Hub using my personal account, and created a repository in this organization. But I can't seem to figure out how to trigger a build in this repository!

I don't have access to the same menus, I don't know what I'm missing here. Any clue? Thanks.

[image: My personal repo]
[image: My organization's repo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to create an 'Automated build', not a simple repository.

In the top left of the UI, go to 'Create' > 'Create Automated Build', then select Github or Bitbucket, select the source repository, then for the 'Repository Namespace & Name' I guess that you should be able to choose your organization for the namespace.
Of course you have to deleted the simple repository you created if you want to use the same repository name.